# omit null columns and also increase performance

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query below, which retrieves data from 3 tables.

```
select *
from vendor_allocation as va, district as d, vendor as v 
where va.district_id = d.id and va.vendor_id = v.id
```

In the result there are many null columns and it takes about 315 msec to execute. I would need to omit the null columns and execute the query faster. I tried using COALESCE but dint get expected results. Please help.

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Also, what is your expected result? List of all Vendors, with district attached?

Comment: To "omit" columns, don't put them in the select list. Another good example on why `select *` should never be used in production queries.

Comment: `select *` returns all columns. Define the columns you want to return by listing them (eg `select somecolumn, someothercolumn, jcwashere from somekindatable`

Comment: I have to add a sentence to the comment of @GordonLinoff : Using commas you performa a `cross join` i.e. `Cartesian Product`. Each row from `vendot_allocation` is combined with each row of `district` which is then combined with `vendor`. This results in a huge amount of `meaningless` data

Comment: @MichaelMairegger In this case, that is not true, as the `where` clause acts like a `join` between the specified key columns, ensuring we only get one row per matching `district_id` and `vendor_id`. Moroever, that was _how_ to join before the 1992 Standard. If your point was that this might be less efficient computationally, I doubt that, as any half-decent query optimiser will make it function just like a `join`; the problem is not computation, but using outdated syntax that poorly conveys meaning.

Comment: @underscore_d ok, well, that is true. I did not read the where clause because of the cross join in the from.

Comment: `In the result there are many null columns` and yet, you have not showed us an example of the actual result, versus the different result that you want. I'm flagging as unclear what you're asking because not enough information has been given.

Answer (score 0):

The following query will return only those values that are present across all the tables. Use a left join if you want to consider the rows in vendor_allocation that might not have corresponding rows present in district / vendor. Those rows will be returned with null as values in the joined table.

```
select *
from vendor_allocation as va
  join district as d using ON va.district_id = d.id
  join vendor as v using ON va.vendor_id = v.id;
```

Using LEFT JOIN

```
select *
from vendor_allocation as va
  left join district as d ON va.district_id = d.id
  left join vendor as v ON va.vendor_id = v.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

This would give you a list of Vendors, with attached district. If you don´t want the ones without district, use an inner join:

```
select v.VendorName, d.DistrictName 
from vendor as v 
left join vendor_allocation as va
on v.id=va.vendor_id 
left join district as d
on va.district_id =d.id
```